# ExtJS 4: Prevent combo box from opening autocomplete list on page (or form) load

Tags: extjs, autocomplete, combobox, extjs4, onload

The combo box is pulling up results (expanding) and focusing on the combo box in a form when my application starts.  How can I prevent automatic focus and expansion on this combo box when the application starts?  Note, I've tried setting the config "selectOnFocus" to true an false, and that didn't do anything.

```
                    width: 540,
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    fieldLabel: 'Table',
                    emptyText: 'keyword search by table name...',
                    store: tableStore,
                    valueField: 'id',
                    displayField: 'value',
                    mode: 'remote',
                    name: 'table',
                    autoSelect: false,
                    selectOnFocus: true,
                    //shadow:true,
                    //forceSelection: true,
                    //triggerAction: 'all',
                    hideTrigger: true,
                    //multiSelect:true,
                    //typeAhead: true,
                    //minChars: 1,

                    listeners: {
                        change: function (obj, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                            tableStore.proxy.extraParams.keyword = newValue;
                            tableStore.load();
                            this.expand();
                        }
                    }  // listeners
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your 'change' listener is triggered on form load.

Do you need this.expand() call at all?

Comment: Okay, I commented the "this.expand();" call.  That's a little better.  It doesn't expand on load, but now it's only expanding the combo box after typing at least 4 characters.  The strange thing is that the event gets called after typing each character--I put in an alert, and it calls the alert.  I can even see the results in the web service call come back.  Why would that be?

Comment: FYI: my results have only two records (options) right now.  I haven't tried adding more.  The two options have a differing character on the 5th character (if that helps).

Comment: could it be that the store load is asynchronous with the expand, and one beats the other?

Comment: Store load is ansync always. the change event will get triggered everytime there is a change of course, however you can buffer it: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-checkChangeBuffer

Comment: I tried all different values for the "checkChangeBuffer" config, but it doesn't cause the combo box to expand until 4 characters.  I tried adding more records, and that's still the case.

Comment: gave you +1 for helping.. we'll figure it out eventually

Comment: Thanks! The 4 char is default. see: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-minChars